# Why getLastKnownLocation return old Location?

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I tried create a marker on my location but Google Map shows old location .

MapsActivity.java

```
private void setUpMap() {

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker").snippet("Snippet"));
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
      mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
    double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("I am here!").snippet("Bla bla bla"));

}
```

Manifest permission

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
 <uses-permission android:name="myapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Android reference manual of [getLastKnownLocation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29)

> Returns a Location indicating the data from the last known location fix obtained from the given provider.
>
> This can be done without starting the provider. Note that this
>   location could be out-of-date, for example if the device was turned
>   off and moved to another location.

In your case you can try defining accuracy in your `Criteria`.

```java
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
```

In general I would use the recommended Fused Location Provider API. You can find a guide [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html).